# How can I get only a text from lists that are on another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

Today I'm learning how to use BeautifulSoup on python, and at one point, I have to work with lists that are on one list. The problem is that I don't know how to apply .text or similar to the lists. Here's my code:

```
 from typing import List
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal

ListaPreciosCromos = list()

ListaUrl = ['https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?category_753_Game%5B%5D=tag_app_495570&category_753_cardborder%5B%5D=tag_cardborder_0&category_753_item_class%5B%5D=tag_item_class_2#p1_price_asc', 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?category_753_Game%5B%5D=tag_app_540190&category_753_cardborder%5B%5D=tag_cardborder_0&category_753_item_class%5B%5D=tag_item_class_2#p1_price_asc', 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?category_753_Game%5B%5D=tag_app_607210&category_753_cardborder%5B%5D=tag_cardborder_0&category_753_item_class%5B%5D=tag_item_class_2#p1_price_asc']
PageCromos = [requests.get(x) for x in ListaUrl]
SoupCromos = [BeautifulSoup(x.content, "html.parser") for x in PageCromos]
PrecioCromos = [x.find_all("span", {"data-price": True}) for x in SoupCromos]

for x in PrecioCromos:
    PreciossinText = x.text

print(PreciossinText)
```

Shows the next error = AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
from typing import List
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal

ListaPreciosCromos = list()

ListaUrl = ['https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?category_753_Game%5B%5D=tag_app_495570&category_753_cardborder%5B%5D=tag_cardborder_0&category_753_item_class%5B%5D=tag_item_class_2#p1_price_asc', 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?category_753_Game%5B%5D=tag_app_540190&category_753_cardborder%5B%5D=tag_cardborder_0&category_753_item_class%5B%5D=tag_item_class_2#p1_price_asc', 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?category_753_Game%5B%5D=tag_app_607210&category_753_cardborder%5B%5D=tag_cardborder_0&category_753_item_class%5B%5D=tag_item_class_2#p1_price_asc']
PageCromos = [requests.get(x) for x in ListaUrl]
SoupCromos = [BeautifulSoup(x.content, "html.parser") for x in PageCromos]
PrecioCromos = [x.find_all("span", {"data-price": True}) for x in SoupCromos]        
        
PreciossinText = [txt.text for x in PrecioCromos for txt in x]

print(PreciossinText)
```

output:

```
['$0.05 USD', '$0.05 USD', '$0.04 USD', '$0.05 USD', '$0.04 USD', '$0.05 USD', '$0.05 USD', '$0.07 USD', '$0.06 USD', '$0.07 USD', '$0.06 USD', '$0.06 USD', '$0.06 USD', '$0.05 USD', '$0.06 USD', '$0.05 USD', '$0.07 USD']
```

Comment: It worked!! It's anyway to keep the prices in their respective lists?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
texts = [result.text for result_set in PrecioCromos for result in result_set]
```